# can't use Font in flutter and use it in app

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, themes, pubspec

I'm trying to add this font
but i don't know why can't use it .

```
 fonts:
    - family: IRANSansX
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-Black.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-DemiBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-ExtraBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-Medium.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-Thin.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansXFaNum-UltraLight.ttf
```

and its theme:

```
theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'IRANSansX'
),
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to give full path. Like this:

```
fonts:
  - family: IRANSansX
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansX.ttf
```

**Edit 1:**

Add others like that as well:

```
fonts:
  - family: IRANSansX
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansX.ttf
      - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansX_bold.ttf
      - asset: assets/fonts/IRANSansX_italic.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

i rename - to _ .
it's work :)